# How to calculate the height of the cell if the table is loaded from 3 types of custom cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iphone application in which I'm loading a `UITableView` from 3 types of custom cells. Which contains different different elements. Now i am doing it by taking the msg content of the cell and find its size and add a constant with it.But when the message is very large the content is showing in the outside part of the cell.I am doing like this `

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  if(sarray==nil||[sarray count]==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
          NSMutableDictionary *dicttable=[sarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
          NSString *stri=[dicttable objectForKey:@"message"];
          NSString *type1=[dicttable objectForKey:@"type"];
          NSString *imagepath1=[dicttable objectForKey:@"image_path"];
         if([type1 isEqualToString:@"m"])
         {  
              if([imagepath1 isEqualToString:@"NA"])
              { 
                   UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15.0];
                   CGSize size1 = [stri sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 130.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
                   NSLog(@"%f",size1.height);
                   return size1.height+75;    
              }
              else
              {
                   UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15.0];
                   CGSize size1 = [stri sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 130.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
                   NSLog(@"%f",size1.height);

                   return size1.height+300;
              }
          }
          else
          {
               UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15.0];
               CGSize size1 = [stri sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 130.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
               NSLog(@"%f",size1.height);
               return size1.height+300;   
          }
     }
}
```

` Can anybody help me in finding a right approach?

Comment: Can you find for one line of text what should be the height? And how much characters are shown in one line. And by calculating total characters in the text, divide it and find number of lines and then find the required size of your cell.

Comment: Can you put the code of your cellForRowAtIndex method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `constrainedToSize:`, you are giving it as 130. Make it as some larger value, say 1000.0f and try.

Comment: Good observation. +1 for that.

Comment: its becuause it is added in the custom cell class with the same frame.eventhough i tried to change to 1000 but still improper height is coming